# OpenGL pixel manipulation for graphic

Tags: ios, opengl-es, pixel

I want to simulate stroking a carpet, so you would have a graphic of a fury carpet and with your finger you can move around and stroke it. I need to shift pixels and create some fake distortion around where I am touching.

Anyone have any tips ?

Firstly I guess do I have enough to work with assuming I have 1 jpeg of the material. Not any skeleton or 3d file, just a flat image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be also improved with 'fur rendering'
I've some examples:

- http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/
- http://www.xbdev.net/directx3dx/specialX/Fur/index.php

or new demo from NVidia:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Fp5N-pOxKA - around 35sec

Comment: target platform is *iPhone* not a graphical power station with industrial computing performance...

Comment: ok, but probably new IPhone will handle some of those techniques (but not from the new gf 680 :)). It depends n what you want to do... is it the main effect in the scene... or maybe some additional effect somewhere in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a typical task to be solved with [OpenGL shaders](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.it/2009/06/opengl-es-2-shaders.html).

Answer (score 1):

As MrTJ says: Shaders is your key here.

Apart from your diffuse use a second texture as your "carpet" map that you modify. Maybe use the like a normal map, storing a directional vector per texel.

Use your "carpet" map in your shader and distort however you like to create your desired carpet effect.